# The Rails way to get the last record of every day

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a table which contains hourly records (spanning multiple days). What I'd like to do is get the last hourly record for each day.

I found the MySQL solution here: [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group) (the accepted answer looks good to me, and more or less makes sense)

However, I'm struggling to implement this with Rails finders, since it's unclear how to do a self join in Rails (all of the documentation applies to association).

So far I've tried this... but to no avail (it says the "id" column is ambiguous).

```
Report.joins("LEFT JOIN reports r2 ON (date('created_at') = date('r2.created_at') AND id < r2.id)").where("r2.id IS NULL")
```

Comment: Did you try using `reports.id`? (Just guessing; can't try anything ATM.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just need to explicitly reference your `reports` table in the SQL:

```
Report.joins("LEFT JOIN reports r2 ON (date('reports.created_at') = date('r2.created_at') AND reports.id < r2.id)").where("r2.id IS NULL")
```

For a more "Railsey" way to achieve this, you might want to look at the `finder_sql` option to [`has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) and create an association to do this.

Comment: That did the trick! thank you, +1 for the finder_sql trick. I'll probably end up implementing it that way. pretty nice!